# Adding a row to a datagridview from another thread in another class

Tags: c#

I have a datagridview, that I am trying to add data to, I have tried the following without an error, but no data was added:

```
mywindowform grid = new mywindowform();
grid.datagridview.rows.add("hello", "it's me");
```

I have also tried:

```
mywindowform grid = new mywindowform();
grid.datagridview.Invoke(new Action(delegate ()
{
    grid.datagridview.Rows.Add("hello", "it's me");
}));
```

and I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.'

If I add the following to the main form, it works, but I need to do it via a class, to seperate code:

```
datagridview.Invoke(new Action(delegate ()
{
    datagridview.Rows.Add("hello", "it's me");
}));
```

So, how can I add rows to my datagridview, from a class that's using a background worker.. I have looked on stackoverflow, and they roccmended to invoke, which I did, but got the error above.

Form with gridview:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private async Task core()
{
    articles article = new articles();

    articles.StatusTextChanged += (sender, text) =>
    {
        Invoke((MethodInvoker)
        delegate {  
            status.Text = text;
        });
    };

    await article.GenerateArticles();
}

private void backgroundworker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    core();
}
```

My class file:

```
class articles
{
    public static event EventHandler<string> StatusTextChanged;

    Form1 grid = new Form1();


    private async Task CreateRow()
    {
        //Fixed window handle issue.
        if (!grid.IsHandleCreated)
        {
            grid.CreateControl();
            MessageBox.Show("1");
            grid.UploadQueue.Invoke((MethodInvoker)
                delegate
                {
                    grid.UploadQueue.Rows.Add("ff", "f", "Generating Audio");
                });
        }
    }

    public async Task GenerateArticles()
    {
        try
        {
            // Get the settings for our database
            DataConnection.DefaultSettings = new MySettings();

            await FindArticles();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Exception
            StatusTextChanged?.Invoke(this, "123" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
    public async Task FindArticles()
    {
        try
        {
            //update label in main form
            StatusTextChanged?.Invoke(this, "Adding to datagrid view.");

            // Add to datagridview
            CreateRow().Wait();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are creating a new form object in articles class, that's why your grid is not updating, also has you are using async and await you don't need background worker

Comment: If I don't create a new object it says UploadQueue does not exist in the current context

Comment: Pass the form to articles class as a parameter

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to c#, how can I do that?

Comment: nvm figure it out... Thank you

Comment: Good, you are welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error states, you can't invoke a control whose window's handle has not yet been created. Please see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.createcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx

Specifically:

> simply calling a control's constructor does not create the Handle.

You can fix this by just showing the window, which will require the handle to be created:

```
mywindowform grid = new mywindowform();
grid.Show();
grid.datagridview.Invoke(new Action(delegate ()
{
    grid.datagridview.Rows.Add("hello", "it's me");
}));
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to show the window yet, you can grab the window's [handle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.handle(v=vs.110).aspx), which will force it to create one:

```
mywindowform grid = new mywindowform();
IntPtr gridHandle = grid.Handle;
grid.datagridview.Invoke(new Action(delegate ()
{
    grid.datagridview.Rows.Add("hello", "it's me");
}));
```